# How to make xcode fall on null pointer

Tags: java, ios, xcode, nullpointerexception

When writing in java, and you try to use some null value, you immediately get "`NullPointerException`"

which is great, because you can figure out why that value may be null.

In IOS , when you try to use some null value, simply nothing happens, the program runs as if nothing happened, it just doesnt show the data.

Is it possible, at least during development, to make xcode raise an exception in such a case ?

Comment: well you can always check for nil

Comment: All you can do is add an explicit check.  (Note that in many cases you should be checking anyway, since a nil result is commonly used as an error indication.)